# <Process> in <Threads> Migrating to Camel 3+ from 2

Tags: java, xml, intellij-idea, apache-camel, spring-camel

I am migrating from camel 2.25.2 to 3.4.0. I noticed that previously in my camel-context.xml, I could put `<process>` in `<threads></threads>`. However, with the upgrade, Intellij has been complaining - "Element process is not allowed here".

For example:

```
<threads>
    <process ref="abcProcessor" />
</threads>
```

However, I could do it outside of . Upon closer inspection, I noticed the following in camel-spring.xsd:

```
<xs:element name="threads" type="tns:threadsDefinition">
```

The ThreadsDefinition class in `org/apache/camel/camel-core-engine/3.4.0/camel-core-engine-3.4.0.jar!/org/apache/camel/model/ThreadsDefinition.class` is different.

I tried finding for some documentation and material but to no avail on how to migrate away to 3.4.0 from 2.25.2 for process tags in threads.

This is the closest I could find: https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/async.html

Is there a way to migrate a custom processor for message exchange that is asynchronous written in DSL?

Would appreciate if the community could give me some insights. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Claus Ibsen, the leading contributor of Apache Camel and the author of Camel In Action clarified on IRC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gKMs.png)

Put `<process>` after `<threads />`